# PrimeFaces dialog is validated only the first time it appears

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

JSF 2.2, PrimeFaces 3.5.

home.xhtml contains a tabview with nested dataTables and add/edit/delete buttons. Each button is supposed to call a dialog with a form and submit/cancel buttons.

The problem is that validation is processed only once (see screenshot) and if I press "Add" / "Cancel" the dialog just hides and no validation is made. And if I try to reopen it once again and input values and hit "Add" -  it just skips validation and renders response. So, basically, it just makes a initial request (if I guessed right).

[image]

Console output for pressing "Add" with empty values 3 times. First click has been processed the way I want it, but the next ones are just hiding the dialog without any validation:

```
2014-01-24 17:56:09,590 DEBUG  [RequestLoggingPhaseListener] Entering JSF Phase: RESTORE_VIEW 1 
2014-01-24 17:56:09,628 DEBUG  [RequestLoggingPhaseListener] Entering JSF Phase: APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2 
2014-01-24 17:56:09,633 DEBUG  [RequestLoggingPhaseListener] Entering JSF Phase: PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3 
2014-01-24 17:56:09,645 DEBUG  [RequestLoggingPhaseListener] Entering JSF Phase: RENDER_RESPONSE 6 
2014-01-24 17:56:13,127 DEBUG  [RequestLoggingPhaseListener] Entering JSF Phase: RESTORE_VIEW 1 
2014-01-24 17:56:13,128 DEBUG  [RequestLoggingPhaseListener] Entering JSF Phase: RENDER_RESPONSE 6 
2014-01-24 17:56:16,557 DEBUG  [RequestLoggingPhaseListener] Entering JSF Phase: RESTORE_VIEW 1 
2014-01-24 17:56:16,558 DEBUG  [RequestLoggingPhaseListener] Entering JSF Phase: RENDER_RESPONSE 6
```

home.xhtml (dialogs are at the bottom of a page):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
              xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
              xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
              xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
              xmlns:ex="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/nsobchuk">
    <h:head>
        <title>Home page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"/>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <h:form id="logout" class="logout" >
            <h:commandButton action="#{loginBean.logout()}" value="logout"/>
        </h:form>

        <p:tabView id="tab" orientation="left">

            <p:tab title="Users">

                <h:form id="form1">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="9">

                        <p:commandButton type="button" value="Add" onclick="dlg1.show()" />


                        <p:commandButton id="editUser" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="dlg2.show()" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedUser == null}"/>
                        <p:dialog id="editUserDialogerDialog" widgetVar="dlg2" header="Sorry" >
                            <h:outputText value="I didn't have enogh time to finish this functionality. Feel free to test other buttons."/>
                        </p:dialog>


                        <p:commandButton id="deleteUser" type="button" onclick="confirmation1.show()" value="Delete" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedUser == null}"/>
                        <p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure you want to delete user?" header="Confirmation"
                                         severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation1">
                            <p:commandButton value="Yes" update=":tab:users" process="@this" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"
                                             oncomplete="confirmation1.hide()" action="#{homeBean.deleteUser}" />
                            <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="confirmation1.hide()" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
                        </p:confirmDialog>

                    </h:panelGrid>

                </h:form>


                <p:dataTable id="users" var="user" value="#{homeBean.users}" 
                             scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250" selectionMode="single"
                             selection="#{homeBean.selectedUser}" rowKey="#{user.userId}"
                             sortMode="single">

                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{homeBean.onUserRowSelect}" update=":tab:form1:deleteUser, :tab:form1:editUser"/> 
                    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{homeBean.onUserRowUnselect}" update=":tab:form1:deleteUser, :tab:form1:editUser"/>

                    <p:column headerText="Login" sortBy="#{user.login}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.login}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Password" sortBy="#{user.password}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.password}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Role" sortBy="#{user.role}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.role}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{user.firstName}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.firstName}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Surname" sortBy="#{user.lastName}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.lastName}"/>
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>

                <ex:exporter target=":tab:users" fileName="Users"/>

            </p:tab>

            <p:tab title="Computers">

                <h:form id="form2">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="9">

                        <p:commandButton type="button" value="Add" onclick="dlg3.show()"/>


                        <p:commandButton id="editComp" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="dlg4.show()" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedComputer == null}"/>
                        <p:dialog id="editCompDialog" widgetVar="dlg4" header="Sorry" >
                            <h:outputText value="I didn't have enogh time to finish this functionality. Feel free to test other buttons."/>
                        </p:dialog>


                        <p:commandButton id="deleteComp" type="button" onclick="confirmation2.show()" value="Delete" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedComputer == null}"/>
                        <p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure you want to delete this computer?" header="Confirmation"
                                         severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation2">
                            <p:commandButton value="Yes" update=":tab:computers" process="@this" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"
                                             oncomplete="confirmation2.hide()" action="#{homeBean.deleteComputer}"/>
                            <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="confirmation2.hide()" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
                        </p:confirmDialog>

                    </h:panelGrid>

                </h:form>


                <p:dataTable id="computers" var="computer" value="#{homeBean.computers}" 
                             scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250" selectionMode="single"
                             selection="#{homeBean.selectedComputer}" rowKey="#{computer.computerId}"
                             sortMode="single" >
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{homeBean.onCompRowSelect}" update=":tab:form2:editComp, :tab:form2:deleteComp"/> 

                    <p:column headerText="Login" sortBy="#{computer.login}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{computer.login}"/>  
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Password" sortBy="#{computer.password}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{computer.password}"/>  
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{computer.computerName}" > 
                        <h:outputText value="#{computer.computerName}"/>  
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="IP address" sortBy="#{computer.ipAddress}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{computer.ipAddress}"/>  
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>

                <ex:exporter target=":tab:computers" fileName="Computers"/>

            </p:tab>

            <p:tab title="Applications">


                <h:form id="form3">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="9">

                        <p:commandButton type="button" value="Add" onclick="dlg5.show()"/>




                        <p:commandButton id="editApp" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="dlg6.show()" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedApplication == null}"/>
                        <p:dialog id="editAppDialog" widgetVar="dlg6" header="Sorry" >
                            <h:outputText value="I didn't have enogh time to finish this functionality. Feel free to test other buttons."/>
                        </p:dialog>


                        <p:commandButton id="deleteApp" type="button" onclick="confirmation3.show()" value="Delete" disabled="#{homeBean.selectedApplication == null}"/>
                        <p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure you want to delete this application?" header="Confirmation"
                                         severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation3">
                            <p:commandButton value="Yes" update=":tab:applications" process="@this" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"
                                             oncomplete="confirmation3.hide()" action="#{homeBean.deleteApplication}"/>
                            <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="confirmation3.hide()" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
                        </p:confirmDialog>

                    </h:panelGrid>

                </h:form>

                <p:dataTable id="applications" var="app" value="#{homeBean.applications}" 
                             scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250" selectionMode="single"
                             selection="#{homeBean.selectedApplication}" rowKey="#{app.appId}"
                             sortMode="single" >

                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{homeBean.onAppRowSelect}" update=":tab:form3:editApp, :tab:form3:deleteApp"/>

                    <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{app.appName}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{app.appName}"/>  
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Vendor" sortBy="#{app.vendorName}" >  
                        <h:outputText value="#{app.vendorName}"/>  
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="License required" sortBy="#{app.licenseRequired}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{app.licenseRequired}"/>  
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>

                <ex:exporter target=":tab:applications" fileName="Applications" />

            </p:tab>

        </p:tabView>


        <p:dialog id="addUserDialog" header="Add Dialog" modal="true" closable="false"
                  widgetVar="dlg1" width="620" >
            <h:form id="dlg1form">
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">

                    <h:outputLabel for="login" value="Login: "/>
                    <p:inputText id="login" required="true"  
                                 label="Login: " maxlength="20" >

                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:message for="login" />

                    <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password: "/>
                    <p:password id="password" required="true" 
                                feedback="true"  label="Password: " maxlength="32"/>
                    <p:message for="password" />

                    <h:outputLabel for="firstName" value="First Name: "/>
                    <p:inputText id="firstName" 
                                 label="First Name: " maxlength="20"/>
                    <p:message for="firstName"/>

                    <h:outputLabel for="lastName" value="Last Name: "/>
                    <p:inputText id="lastName"
                                 label="Last Name: " maxlength="20"/>
                    <p:message for="lastName"/>

                    <h:outputLabel for="role" value="Role: "/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="role" required="true" style="width: 80px;" >
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="user" itemValue="ROLE_USER" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="admin" itemValue="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:message for="role"/>

                </h:panelGrid>

                <p:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="dlg1.hide()" update="@form">
                    <p:resetInput target="addUserDialog"  />
                </p:commandButton>

                <p:commandButton value="Add" update="@form" immediate="false"
                                 oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) dlg1.hide()" />
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>



        <p:dialog id="addCompDialog" header="Add Dialog" draggable="true" closable="false" modal="true"
                  widgetVar="dlg3" width="600">

            <h:form id="dlg3form">
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">

                    <h:outputLabel for="pclogin" value="Login: "/>
                    <p:inputText id="pclogin" required="true"  
                                 label="Login: " maxlength="20">
                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:message for="pclogin"/>

                    <h:outputLabel for="pcpassword" value="Password: "/>
                    <p:password id="pcpassword" required="true" 
                                feedback="true"  label="Password: " maxlength="32"/>
                    <p:message for="pcpassword" />

                    <h:outputLabel for="compName" value="Computer Name: "/>
                    <p:inputText id="compName" required="true"
                                 label="Computer Name: " maxlength="20"/>
                    <p:message for="compName"/>

                    <h:outputLabel for="ipaddress" value="IP address: "/>
                    <p:inputText id="ipaddress" required="true"
                                 label="IP address: " maxlength="20"/>
                    <p:message for="ipaddress"/>

                </h:panelGrid>

                <p:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true" onclick="dlg3.hide()" process="@this" update="@form">
                    <p:resetInput target="addCompDialog" />
                </p:commandButton>

                <p:commandButton value="Add" update="@form" 
                                 oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) dlg3.hide()" />
            </h:form>

        </p:dialog>




        <p:dialog id="addAppDialog" header="Add Dialog" draggable="true" closable="false" modal="true"
                  widgetVar="dlg5" width="600" >

            <h:form id="dlg5form">
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:outputLabel for="appName" value="Name: "/>
                    <p:inputText id="appName" required="true"  
                                 label="Name: "/>
                    <p:message for="appName"/>

                    <h:outputLabel for="vendorName" value="Vendor: "/>
                    <p:inputText id="vendorName" 
                                 label="Vendor: " required="true" />
                    <p:message for="vendorName"/>

                    <h:outputLabel for="appLicense" value="Requires license: "/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="appLicense" required="true" style="width: 80px;" >
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="True" itemValue="#{true}" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="False" itemValue="#{false}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:message for="appLicense"/>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <p:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true" onclick="dlg5.hide()" update="@form" process="@this">
                    <p:resetInput target="addAppDialog" />
                </p:commandButton>

                <p:commandButton value="Add" update="@form" 
                                 oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) dlg5.hide()"/>
            </h:form>

        </p:dialog> 


    </h:body>

</ui:component>
```

HomeBean:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class HomeBean extends BaseBean {

    private static final String editUserBtn = "tab:form1:editUser";
    private static final String deleteUserBtn = "tab:form1:deleteUser";
    private static final String editCompBtn = "tab:form2:editComp";
    private static final String deleteCompBtn = "tab:form2:deleteComp";
    private static final String editAppBtn = "tab:form3:editApp";
    private static final String deleteAppBtn = "tab:form3:deleteApp";
    @Autowired
    private HibernateDBManager hibernateDBManager;
    private List<User> users;
    private List<Computer> computers;
    private List<Application> applications;
    private User selectedUser, newUser;
    private Computer selectedComputer, newComputer;
    private Application selectedApplication, newApplication;
    private RequestContext rc;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setUsers(hibernateDBManager.getAllUsers());
        setComputers(hibernateDBManager.getAllComputers());
        setApplications(hibernateDBManager.getAllApplications());
        newUser = new User();
        newComputer = new Computer();
        newApplication = new Application();
        rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    }

    public void addUser() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        if (newUser != null && newUser.getPassword() != null) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md.update(newUser.getPassword().getBytes());
            String hash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16);
            newUser.setPassword(hash);
            if (hibernateDBManager.insertUser(newUser)) {
                users.add(newUser);
            }
        }
    }

    public void editUser() {
        if (selectedUser != null) {
            hibernateDBManager.updateUser(selectedUser);
            users.set(users.indexOf(selectedUser), selectedUser);
            selectedUser = null;
            rc.update(deleteUserBtn);
            rc.update(editUserBtn);
        }
    }

    public void deleteUser() throws IOException {
        if (selectedUser != null) {
            if (hibernateDBManager.deleteUserById(selectedUser.getUserId()) > 0) {
                users.remove(selectedUser);
                selectedUser = null;
                rc.update(deleteUserBtn);
                rc.update(editUserBtn);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addComputer() {
        if (newComputer != null && hibernateDBManager.insertComputer(newComputer)) {
            computers.add(newComputer);
        }
    }

    public void deleteComputer() {
        if (selectedComputer != null) {
            if (hibernateDBManager.deleteComputerById(selectedComputer.getComputerId()) > 0) {
                computers.remove(selectedComputer);
                selectedComputer = null;
                rc.update(editCompBtn);
                rc.update(deleteCompBtn);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addApplication() {
        if (newApplication != null && hibernateDBManager.insertApplication(newApplication)) {
            applications.add(newApplication);
        }
    }

    public void deleteApplication() {
        if (selectedApplication != null) {
            if (hibernateDBManager.deleteApplicationById(selectedApplication.getAppId()) > 0) {
                applications.remove(selectedApplication);
                selectedApplication = null;
                rc.update(editAppBtn);
                rc.update(deleteAppBtn);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onUserRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        setSelectedUser((User) event.getObject());
    }

    public void onUserRowUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {
        setSelectedUser(null);
    }

    public void onCompRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        setSelectedComputer((Computer) event.getObject());
    }

    public void onAppRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        setSelectedApplication((Application) event.getObject());
    }

    //Getters etc.
    }
```

I'd like to keep the dialog opened and validated each time user presses "Add" and not only once. Can anybody help me achieve this with my code or point me to the solution? (similar answered question with rating -1 didn't help me) Every answer is highly appreciated.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, guys. I found a solution by myself. What I did to make it work was giving a panelGrid element inside a form an id an updating panelGrid instead of a whole form.

So, "Add" button was changed to:

```
<p:commandButton value="Add" 
    update=":dlg1form:dt, :tab:users"
    action="#{homeBean.addUser}"  
    oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) dlg1.hide()" />
```

and panelGrid, which contains input fields:

```
<h:form id="dlg1form">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="dt">
```

This helped me to validate input fields on every click and not just once.

Sincerely hope that this will help someone.

Cheers!

Comment: If you answered your own question correctly, you can still accept your answer as accepted. It won't give you any reputation, but it will mark the answer as the solution. It will help other people find the answer more quickly if they encoutner the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem : having a `update="@form"` or `update="yourFormName"` inside my `<p:commandButton>` prevented the dialog from being kept when a validation error occured.

This might be due to the fact that including the update form command regenerate the whole dialog but doesn't trigger the `dialogWidgetVar.show()` js command.

I solved the issue by nesting a `<p:fragment autoUpdate="true">` inside the dialog.  Then, you can remove the `update` keyword inside the triggering commandButton since every component inside the fragment  will be updated.  The result is that the `<p:dialog>` and `</p:dialog>` tags are not replaced when the client receives the Ajax response. My working code is as follows :

```
<h:form id="locations_editer_creer">
    <p:dialog id="location_dlg" widgetVar="locationDlg" header="#{msgs.LocationCreerNouvelle}" width="600" dynamic="false" closeOnEscape="true"
                      minimizable="true" maximizable="true" modal="true" >

        <p:fragment autoUpdate="true">

            your form inputs e.g. <p:inputText .../>

            <p:commandButton id="OK" value="OK"
              actionListener="#{locationsControleur.confirmer()}"
              oncomplete="traiteRequeteCreationLoc(xhr, status, args)"
              styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>

        </p:fragment>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

This technique is described inside the excellent `PrimeFaces Beginner's Guide` book by K. Siva Prasad Reddy (Packt Publishing), p. 54 : Partial Processing and Rendering using the Fragment component.

Hope this can help others.

Comment: Nice, I like this solution.